# Capture photo with overlay picture

Tags: ios, camera, overlay

I am trying to capture a photo with an overlay image using iPhone camera, but after surfing net for days, I still can't find the answer for it.  How can this be done? I am using Xcode 4.3.2.

Comment: do you want to apply an overlay for the captured image or show the overlay while the user is taking the image from the camera?

Comment: show the overlay while user is taking the image
and also apply the overlay to captured image

Answer (score 2):

I've followed the example here http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1273 with really good results.

Shouldn't be all that hard to apply your overlay to the final captured image either.

Comment: I saw this tutorial last week,
but it isn't what I want...
anyway, thanks

Comment: What is it that you are looking for, then?

Comment: this tutorial is only show the example display the overlay view,
what I want is capture image together with the overlay view,
something similar like print screen

Comment: Excellent example.  Remember that, after downloading this project, you need to go into the AROverlayExample Project, Build Settings, Build Options, and change the "Compiler for C/C++" to "Default Compiler".   If you don't XCode will moan that it doesn't recognise the outdated compiler in this Xcode project file.   (Sigh...)